# Help - Possible Bad Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, raid

Okay, first let me preface this with an apology. I was persuaded to set up my Plex server in Ubuntu because it would be 'easy and lightweight'. However, my knowledge of Linux commands in general could barely fill a thimble (I have trouble installing or unpacking .tar files - or whatever it is you do with them - and am heavily reliant on the GUI). That being said, if I can recover the data, I will move it to a backup drive and rebuild Plex from the ground up on Windows so I can support it if something goes wrong. How we got to this point is irrelevant...I just need some help to hopefully get things back up and I will take steps to keep this from happening again. I am also new to reddit for the sole purpose of this post so, here goes.

The current setup is on a NAS with 4x 3 TB drives with my 128 GB SSD running Ubuntu. I followed a Plex guide in setting up my RAID and I actually know so little about what commands were run that I am not 100% sure what RAID has been set up - if any. At first I just started experiencing some slowness. I rebooted, as per my norm, but the issue persisted. I then started seeing errors for one drive in particular, I couldn't import the RAID Pool because it wasn't available. Disk management showed that another 1 MB partition had showed up randomly on that drive. At one point it said the drive was re-silvering at the rate of 1 KB/s and research said that if a reboot to get it unstuck would be safe but later the drive wouldn't show up at all. Honestly, I just feel completely at a loss because I don't know how to proceed in order to troubleshoot the drive. Do I have to unmount the RAID Pool before I try unmounting the drive to look at the partitions? Any advice or commands to help figure out what's going on would be deeply appreciated.

Here is the output from my ORIGINAL build when things were functioning:

```
name@name:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1D7A0502-C7BB-A343-ACAF-BAC53188F757

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048 5860515839 5860513792  2.7T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sda9  5860515840 5860532223      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1

Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A91EFAE9-97A3-C849-8E03-273BBD27BAB2

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 5860515839 5860513792  2.7T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdb9  5860515840 5860532223      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1

Disk /dev/sdc: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DF70D700-B395-714F-87F4-0A556CD508A0

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 5860515839 5860513792  2.7T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdc9  5860515840 5860532223      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1

Disk /dev/sdd: 118 GiB, 126701535232 bytes, 247463936 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbd4a320c

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1       193664 247463935 247270272 117.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sde: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 20609266-DE2E-D547-A559-6A7BFA5F6A3A

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sde1        2048 5860515839 5860513792  2.7T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sde9  5860515840 5860532223      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1

Disk /dev/sdf: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x48168c26

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdf1  *         2048 232441855 232439808 110.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sdf2       232443902 234440703   1996802   975M  5 Extended
/dev/sdf5       232443904 234440703   1996800   975M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Here is the current status that I can see thus far:

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 295.7 MiB, 310079488 bytes, 605624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 295.6 MiB, 309968896 bytes, 605408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 32.3 MiB, 33869824 bytes, 66152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 32.3 MiB, 33865728 bytes, 66144 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 55.5 MiB, 58134528 bytes, 113544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 55.4 MiB, 58130432 bytes, 113536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1D7A0502-C7BB-A343-ACAF-BAC53188F757

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048 5860515839 5860513792  2.7T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sda9  5860515840 5860532223      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A91EFAE9-97A3-C849-8E03-273BBD27BAB2

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 5860515839 5860513792  2.7T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdb9  5860515840 5860532223      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/sdc: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 20609266-DE2E-D547-A559-6A7BFA5F6A3A

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 5860515839 5860513792  2.7T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdc9  5860515840 5860532223      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/sdd: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x48168c26

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *         2048 232441855 232439808 110.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sdd2       232443902 234440703   1996802   975M  5 Extended
/dev/sdd5       232443904 234440703   1996800   975M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

The GUI picture of the drives did show the 4th drive as appearing at one point but I believe it showed /dev/sdc and had a partition of 1 MB and the /dev/sdc1 partition of 3 TB wasn't orange (if that matters, I thought it was somehow no longer the primary partition, but again, I don't know enough about Ubuntu) in addition to the /dev/sdc9 of 8.4 MB.

I saw this and under more research and advice, I tried GParted, but it wouldn't see the drive. I did run a command that showed me a status at one point that said it was re-silvering but I can't remember off the top of my head. I tried to install TestDisk but couldn't figure out the installer commands. When the re-silvering process seemed stuck, I rebooted. Now the drive won't appear at all and I am afraid to proceed further because I don't know what I'm doing and I don't want to further damage the integrity of the drive. Any help, again, is greatly appreciated. I'm not sure what else to do at this point.

Comment: You mention plex server and wanting a light system, so I gather Ubuntu Server - but you've provided no release details. You also mention a GUI multiple times; given you mentioned wanting a *light* system that implies other than Ubuntu Desktop - but again no specifics. Your pastes only include fdisk & file-system commands (logical issues, not physical disk issue or SMART (ie. disk diags; this applies in windows & other OSes too) so I'm a little confused - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools  Please clarify your OS & release at least.

Comment: The setup is a bit confusing. It's not clear what RAID configuration you have or why you are using RAID to begin with. Hopefully you are aware that [RAID is not a backup](https://www.raidisnotabackup.com/) solution.  In fact, using RAID as your primary storage can actually increase the chance of data loss. Striping is more likely for something for something to go wrong and mirroring also mirrors mistakes and many other forms of corruption.

Comment: also asked on https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/poesup/help_possible_bad_drive/.

Comment: RAID wasn't meant to be a backup, I didn't get into the details at the time but I was still in the setup process for things (getting data transferred over) and was still prepping my backup solution. Drives were still in shipping at the time and I was over eager to get started. When I created the RAID, I was following a guide that I didn't properly understand so honestly, I really am not sure what type of raid setup is in place. But I'm going to try to boot up a live version of linux to see if I can't examine the drives.